# use "grep" command to find txt files containing telephone number

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, grep

use "grep" command to find txt files containing telephone number.

telephone number format could be:

```
"***-*******"
"**********"
"*** *******"
"***-***-****"
```

How to write it?

Comment: I think the regular expression you want to use is /\d{3}[\s\-]?\d{3}-?\d{4}/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

numbers are 3 digits (\d{3}), space or dash [\s-], 3 digits (\d{3}), space or dash [\s-], 4 digits (\d{4}).

```
grep '\d{3}[\s\-]{0,1}\d{3}[\s\-]{0,1}\d{4}' infile.txt
```

**Edit** @Mark and Jed - good advice - made updates based off recommendations

Comment: this also accepts #s like `123 - - - - ------456 -- ---7890` which would be a pretty stupidly formatted phone number. i'd change the *s to ?s and perhaps use a backreference for the second delimiter

Comment: If you had actually given the example grep command, I'd give you a +1. (Hint, hint).

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat file
test 1234567890 test
blah 123-4567890 junk junk 546-3345622 junk
blah blah 123 4575463 sdfsljads 123_456_4356 end
123--4567890

$ grep -Po '\d{3}[\s\-_]?\d{3}[\s\-_]?\d{4}'  file
1234567890
123-4567890
546-3345622
123 4575463
123_456_4356

$ ruby -ne 'puts $_.scan(/\d{3}[\s\-_]?\d{3}[\s\-_]?\d{4}/)' file
1234567890
123-4567890
546-3345622
123 4575463
123_456_4356
```